# Installing Mathematica's package in Linux

Tags: packages, linux

I copied the package folder (ProPac, http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~hgk22/software/ProPac/ProPac.html) in  `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` in Linux mint. 
But when I called it by

```
<<ProPac`
```

the ouput is

```
Get::noopen: Cannot open ProPac`. >>
$Failed
```

I tried install it from File menu but appears the same error.

But in Windows OS I have no problem with installation of this package and using it.

Comment: Try calling the Needs function on the package while manually specifying the packages location. This will let you know whether their is an issue Import or not.

Comment: Is the file located somewhere where Mathematica can find it? Evaluate $Path to see where Mathematica is looking for files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just rename the kernel directory to Kernel.

Then it works.

Unix is case sensititve.

Comment: Dear Rolf, Thank you very much.